# Copy SQLite database to android device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm already created my application used Android Studio. The database also completely done, when I run my application using emulator, that application can access the data in database. But the problem is when I try to run my application to the phone/android device, the database cannot be access. I run it by "choose a running device", where my phone already connected to the PC and already has been "root". thank you so much for help.

Comment: Do you mean not able to access database programattically or through file explorer in DDMS?

Comment: No, i'm not able to access database when I run in a phone. I'm already check in DDMS and the database is in there. i'm also run using emulator, there have no any problem with database because i able to access it. thank you

Comment: Your question describes your problem but misses more details on what you do. Please edit your question and add the code how you load the database and information about how you integrate it into your app (e.g. as asset).